# TriggeredFunctionData null when entering Webjob SDK function

Tags: rabbitmq, azure-webjobssdk

I am trying to use a rabbitMQ extension to webjob SDK (https://github.com/Sarmaad/WebJobs.Extensions.RabbitMQ) to have it trigger when something is put on the queue.

The triggering works fine, but the content is never passed into my function.

I downloaded the source for the extension so i could debug inside it and I see that the content of the queue is delivered successfully and the extension repackages it into a TriggeredFunctionData object. The object is then passed to my function through the Webjob executor. 
However as I step into my function this object is null.

Listener method from extension lib:

```
        _consumer.Received += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var triggerValue = new RabbitQueueTriggerValue {MessageBytes = args.Body};
            if (args.BasicProperties != null)
            {
                triggerValue.MessageId = args.BasicProperties.MessageId;
                triggerValue.ApplicationId = args.BasicProperties.AppId;
                triggerValue.ContentType = args.BasicProperties.ContentType;
                triggerValue.CorrelationId = args.BasicProperties.CorrelationId;
                triggerValue.Headers = args.BasicProperties.Headers;
            }

            var result = _executor.TryExecuteAsync(new TriggeredFunctionData{TriggerValue = triggerValue}, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

When debugging I can see that Triggervalue contains my message data.

My function being executed:

```
public static async Task ProcessRabbitMqTopicStatusMessage([RabbitQueueTrigger("tempq")]
     [RabbitQueueBinder("myexchange", "myroutingkey", "myerrorq",autoDelete:true,durable:true, execlusive:false)]
     TriggeredFunctionData message,
        TextWriter logger)
    {   

        if (message != null)
        {

        }


     }
```

This method is triggered successfully, but message is always null.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your user function **shouldn't** bind directly to TriggeredFunctionData.   That's an intermediate object used by the triggering infrastructure which gets converted to final destination objects to match your function's signature.
The binding author (in this case, RabbitMQ at the GitHub site you linked to) is what defines the possible objects that it can bind to.

From http://www.sarmaad.com/2016/11/azure-webjobs-and-rabbitmq/, here was an example of their usage:

```
public void IntegrateApprovedProductToMarketPlace(
[RabbitQueueBinder("product", "product.approved", "error")]
[RabbitQueueTrigger("integration-product-approved")]
ProductApproved message, TextWriter log)
{
[handle message here]
}
```